# Problem using ConstantArray in FindRoot

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I ran into a strange problem, where using [`ConstantArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html) inside [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) results in a [`FindRoot::jsing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/FindRoot/jsing) error.  Here's a minimal example, with the first instance working and the second failing:

```
FindRoot[{0, 0} == {x^2 + y^2 - 1, x - y}, {x, 0.1}, {y, 0.2}]
(* {x -> 0.707107, y -> 0.707107} *)

FindRoot[ConstantArray[0, 2] == {x^2 + y^2 - 1, x - y}, {x, 0.1}, {y, 0.2}]
(* FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {x,y} = {0.1,0.2}. Try perturbing the initial point(s). *)
(* {x -> 0.1, y -> 0.2} *)
```

Any idea why this occurs?

Anyhow, here's an easy workaround:

```
FindRoot[Table[0, 2] == {x^2 + y^2 - 1, x - y}, {x, 0.1}, {y, 0.2}]
(* {x -> 0.707107, y -> 0.707107} *)
```

Comment: Problem is probably due to `FindRoot` having the attribute `HoldAll`. Change to `FindRoot[Thread[ConstantArray[0, 2] == {x^2 + y^2 - 1, x - y}], {x, 
  0.1}, {y, 0.2}]`

Comment: Even easier workaround: `FindRoot[{x^2 + y^2 - 1, x - y}, {x, 0.1}, {y, 0.2}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, that helps.  Do you have any insight into why the `Table[0, 2]` version works without `Thread`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I was about to reply that this was just a minimal example and that the real problem was deep in a much more complex function, but come to think of it, your comment would probably work there too.  Sometimes the obvious answer is right there staring at you.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem with `ConstantArray` appears to be that it is packed. `Needs["Developer\`"]; 

FindRoot[FromPackedArray@ConstantArray[0, 2] == {x^2 + y^2 - 1, 
   x - y}, {x, 0.1}, {y, 0.2}]` works.

Comment: @Bob 's remark is further borne out by the failure of the "reversed" ``FindRoot[Developer`ToPackedArray@Table[0, 2] == {x^2 + y^2 - 1, x - y}, {x, 0.1}, {y, 0.2}]`` -- Still seems like a bug to me.